# Where do I find the code behind a dynamically generated .aspx file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic

I'm trying to debug a dynamically generated aspx file, which is throwing an error. I've been unable to find where the dynamic code is generated from. When debugging the application, I get an error from the line

```
    _dialog.dialog('close');
```

as there is no dialog to be closed. I'm looking to find where I can change this in the static code, but don't know how to trace dynamic code. The call stack goes back only one function to JScript global code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VS2012+, use the project window as it shows the actual generated code (during runtime).  Also don't dismiss the new IE11 developer tools (F12).  You can get loads of information on where the source is coming from.